# Distributing Python script tools using methods not in Sharing Tools section of ArcGIS Help?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I want to be able to distribute a custom script and it seems that I cannot create a .tbx file, so I looked into the other methods, but they are all only for Python modules it seems.

What I want to be able to do is have the user still be able to pull up the dialog box prompting for input when they click on the tool, how do I go about packaging the external libraries that I used for this script and distribute it such that the user can simply import the tool into his toolbox and click on it and it will pull up the dialog box for user input?

Comment: Why can't you share your tbx file?  What error do you get?

Comment: well its not that I can't share a .tbx file, its that you cannot include scripts and external libraries in a .tbx file.

Comment: I was considering using the tool share file system, but I can't seem to locate it?

Comment: I'm away from a computer with ArcGIS on it at the moment.  Sorry!  I don't want to seem rude not replying though!

Comment: In 10.1, they are introducing the [Python toolbox](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000)

Comment: @kenbuja, do you know of any way to essentially do that for 10.0? Would you create a scratch workspace or .mxd file and then save the default toolbox settings and then send around that mxd file in addition to the python script with its libraries and then add the path in properties upon getting the tool?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that

Comment: Nowadays, I think you should investigate using a Geoprocessing package to try and do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External libraries need to be installed separately.  You can import standalone modules but if they require installation of dlls etc you are out of luck (ie SciPy, Numpy etc etc)

Comment: I'm not sure, but are python files that are imported considered dlls?

Comment: not unless they have to be installed separately, most python modules (aka *.py) may need to be imported but will need to be distributed with the calling code or installed separately (ie SciPy or Numpy)